# Laravel 4 Namespaces routes and namespaces in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I was trying to order my controllers in Laravel 4 and adding them some nice namespaces

So i wanted routes like this 
admin/scholar-groups
And i wanted the controller to be in a subfolder called 'admin'

So I have a route file like this:

```
   //Admin Routes
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'admin'), function()
{
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
  {
    # Scholar Groups Controller
    Route::group(['before' => 'auth|adminGroup'], function()
    {
      Route::resource('scholar-groups', 'ScholarGroupController');
    });

  });
});
```

Then I added a namespace to my scholarGroupController which is in a subfolder named 'admin'

```
    <?php namespace admin;
class ScholarGroupController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /scholargroup
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $scholarGroups = ScholarGroup::paginate(10);
        return View::make('scholar_groups.index',compact('scholarGroups'));
    }
```

But whenever I try to access to my index action in Controller I get this error.

```
Class 'admin\ScholarGroup' not found
```

So the namespaces is affecting my model namespace in the following line

```
$scholarGroups = ScholarGroup::paginate(10);
```

How do I avoid the namespace affecting this model class namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is in the `admin` namespace, and referring to other classes from there will be relative to that namespace.

So you need to refer to your model with a preceding backslash (just like you did with `BaseController`) like this:

```
<?php namespace admin;

class ScholarGroupController extends \BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $scholarGroups = \ScholarGroup::paginate(10);

        return View::make('scholar_groups.index',compact('scholarGroups'));
    }
}
```

or import it above the class declaration like this:

```
<?php namespace admin;

use ScholarGroup;

class ScholarGroupController extends \BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $scholarGroups = ScholarGroup::paginate(10);

        return View::make('scholar_groups.index',compact('scholarGroups'));
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to do `Route::group` twice. you can do this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin'), function() {
    // . . .
});
```